# Use XAML data binding to bind each end of a Line to the center of two shapes on a Canvas

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I have a Canvas in Silverlight with two ellipses on it.  The ellipses are animated via events in the code behind.  I have added a line two the canvas and I would like each end of the line to be bound to the center of each ellipse.  Is it possible to do this in XAML databinding or will I have to manually move the end of the line around in code?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried it, you may be able to achieve something using an ElementName Binding to bind between the Canvas.Top (and Left) properties of the ellipse and the line. You'll probably need a converter to offset that to center of the ellipse.